# Both quadratic and linear term are insignificant

Tags: regression, logarithm, quadratic-form, centering, age

I am trying to fit a model which has age as a control variable and mental health score as my dependent variable. I centered the age because 0 is not meaningful in my analysis. I tried age, age^2, log(age) and age^1/2, all of them are not significant with p-value>0.1. Is there anything that I did wrong?[image: Here is the plot between mental health score and age]

Comment: Is this a scatter plot of mental health score against age? Visually, there doesn't seem to be a relationship between the two variables and a transformation won't change that. Since there is overplotting, it might be informative to add a nonparametric smooth with `scatter.smooth(data$mental_health ~ data$age)` but the only clear pattern is that there are fewer subjects over 60 in the sample.

Comment: Use hexagonal binning to make such a scatterplot, with color-coded frequencies (see for example https://hbiostat.org/bbr/desc.html).  But the bigger problem is that you are "playing with the data".  You might just stick with a Spearman $\rho$ rank correlation, but if you want to model then pre-specify a single flexible model (e.g., cubic spline) and stick with it.  And don't test individual terms.  Do chunk tests on all terms involving the predictor, combined, the assess evidence for association (non-flatness).  More at https://hbiostat.org/rmsc